# UIScrollView doesn't scroll second time it's opened

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swift3

I have UIViewController that have UIScrollView with lots of Labels and ImageViews inside and I set height of UIScrollView using:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
   scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.contentView.frame.width, height:
            self.labelTitle1.frame.height +
            self.labelTitle2.frame.height +
            self.labelTitle3.frame.height +
            ...
            self.imageView1.frame.height +
            self.imageView2.frame.height +
            self.imageView3.frame.height +
            ...)
}
```

This works for the first time when I open that UIViewController, but if I go back using UINavigationController and then open again that UIViewController with the same post I'm not able to scroll down.

If I then open another post inside that UIViewController I'm able to scroll down but only for the first time it's opened.

Same thing is for all the posts, they scroll only the first time when they are opened.

Why is that happening and how to fix it?

Comment: try calling `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` in `viewWillAppear()`

Comment: @Danoram I tried but I'm still not able to scroll

Comment: try adding `super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()` just before `scrollView.contentSize = ...`

Comment: @Danoram I added `super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()` but nothing happened, I'm still not able to scroll

Comment: ok, um try moving this code to `viewDidAppear`

Comment: @Danoram I moved the code to `viewDidAppear` and now it works! Thank you!

Comment: no problem :D glad it worked!

Comment: You might answer your own question with your solution so as to help others who find this question with a similar problem.

Comment: @Danoram I can do that. I thought maybe it's better that you answer question so I could mark it as correct answer and you will get points

Comment: ok sure :) that's awesome of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your code to `viewDidAppear()` so that you end up with something looking like

```
override func viewDidAppear() {

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.contentView.frame.width, height:
        self.labelTitle1.frame.height +
        self.labelTitle2.frame.height +
        self.labelTitle3.frame.height +
        ...
        self.imageView1.frame.height +
        self.imageView2.frame.height +
        self.imageView3.frame.height +
        ...)
}
```